# Get Data After Login with Android

Tags: android, post, get

I created two fields for username and password in an activity.I want to login with that values to my site.I have username and password for my account and I want to get the information after logged in to the site.
Can Any one Suggest me to how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial

http://www.korri.net/tutorials/android/android-http-request-tutorial.html

It is simple, but it has what you need. 
You basically make http request using the AsyncTask class as helper for creating thread that will make the call, since android doesn't allow that on the main UI thread.

And make sure you pass the username and password as paramters

```
//Any other parameters you would like to set
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",param1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",param2));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

or just add them to the url

```
String url = "http://example.com/login?id=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;
```